# How can I modify a property value in QJsonValue or QJsonObject?

Tags: qt

I haven't found any method on those qt object that seems useful for modifying properties. See my code comment for exactly what I want to do.

```cpp
for (const QJsonValue& value : array) {
    // here I want to set the value for the 'id' key to 0
    addRecording(new Recording(value.toObject()));
}
```

I am not picky about the approach

- It doesn't matter to me if I modify the QJsonValue or the QJsonObject returned by the toObject method.
- I am fine with copying and creating a temporary variable if that would be needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a solution to this:

```
    for (const QJsonValue& value : array) {
        QJsonObject obj = value.toObject();

        auto iterator = obj.find("id");
        obj.erase(iterator);
        obj.insert("id", 1000);

        addRecording(new Recording(obj));
    }
```